# NSNumber from array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an array, and I am trying to get an integer in my array into a int or NSInteger. It uses NSDictionaries. The following code does not work:

```
int color = [[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"color"];
```

Note that I am using a Core Data Fetch that saves into an array called "records".

Thanks

Comment: Be specific when you say doesn't work !!!! What doesn't work. What exception it raises. Does [[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"color"] returns string or something else which you are assigning to int. Or is records objectAtIndex:0 isn't dictionary so valueForKey: cannot be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int color = [[[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"color"] intValue];
```

Comment: Then your records object is empty

Comment: @sosborn How-I have this code `NSString *prize = [[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"prize"];` and it works fine. . .

Comment: Is that code is the same location? Or is it in a different method?